# UDP Packet size and packet losses

Tags: networking, network-programming

I've been writing a program that uses a stop and wait protocol on top of UDP to send packets over LAN and also over WAN. I've recently been testing my program and have noticed that the packet loss rate is higher for larger packets (approaching 64k bytes). Intuitively this makes sense but what are the actual reasons for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UDP packets greater than the [MTU size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) of the network that carries them will be automatically split up into multiple packets, and then reassembled by the recipient.  If any of those multiple sub-packets gets dropped, then the receiver will drop the rest of them as well.

So for example if you send a 63k UDP packet, and it goes over Ethernet, it will get broken up into 47+ smaller "fragment" packets (because Ethernet's MTU is 1500 bytes, but some of those are used for UDP headers, etc, so the amount of user-data-space available in a UDP packet is smaller than that).  The receiver will only "see" that UDP packet if all 47+ of those fragment-packets make it through okay.  If just one of those fragment-packets gets dropped, the whole operation fails.

Comment: You can't send a 64k packet. The maximum UDP payload is 65507 bytes.

Comment: Well, if we're going to pick nits, a UDP packet with a 65507 byte payload is 65535 bytes long (including the headers) -- one byte short of 64KiB.  But for the sake of accuracy I'll change my example to 63k.

Comment: The effect of this is a small amount of packet loss can impact performance significantly.  In this example, if you had 2% packet loss, you'd *roughly* on average lose 50% of your packets causing a significant drop in throughput.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19057666/84206

Answer (score 0):

Well, data networks are far from reliable; packets get dropped all the time. Overloaded routers, full buffers and corrupt packets are some of the reasons. Since UDP has no flow control capabilities, it can't slow down if for example the receiving end is overloaded.

As Jeremy explained, the bigger the payload, the more packets it is going to be split into, and therefore a bigger chance of losing some of them.

UDP is used in cases where a dropped packet here in there won't affect anything or cases that you need something to get there in time or not at all. (VOIP, streaming video etc)

Answer (score 0):

Its all about IP fragmentation and defragmentation. Packet more than MTU would be fragmented and has to be defragmented at the final host, there are also chances the fragments gets fragmented again on the path and which again can add the delay. sometimes if some N/W element is configured for layer 4 filtering then it defragments(not the final host) apply rules and then again frgaments and forward. Thats the reason the applicaiton which need performance always try to send data with size <= (MTU-ETHHDR-IPHDR)