# Is there a way to send a whole array of integers at the same time without loops?

Tags: c++, arrays, audio, udp, esp8266

I want to send udp packets of my readings from a microphone (connected to my esp8266) to my computer. To do this i was thinking to send arrays of 1000 elements each per packet, but i can not get it to work.

to send udp packets i use:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

mic = analogRead(micPin);

Udp.beginPacket(DESTINATION_IP, DESTINATION_PORT);
Udp.write(/*the packet*/);
Udp.endPacket();
```

This is not all code the rest consists of connecting to my local wifi and setting up udp.

I have tried to convert the integers to char arrays, to then send them as a kind of string of 1000 characters, but i havent succeeded in doing so.

I tried to get the individual digits of every number (that i read from my mic) and to typecast these individual digits to chars:

```
mic = analogRead(micPin);

int getDigits(){
  int length = 3; 
  int digit[length]; 
  int a = mic; 
  int j; 

  switch (mic >= 100){
  case true:
    j = 2;
    length = j + 1; 
    break;
  case false:
    j = (mic >= 10) ? 1 : 0; 
    length = j + 1; 
    break;
  }

  while (a >= 1) {
    digit[j] = (a % 10) + 48; 
    a /= 10;
    j--; 
  }

  if (length == 3){
    return digit[0] + digit[1] + digit[2]; 
  }else if (length == 2){
    return digit[0] + digit[1]; 
  }else {
    return digit[0]; 
  }

}
```

The thought is that "return digit[0] + digit[1] + digit[2]" would give me for example 49, 50, 51. and not 150 (the sum),so that i can then do (char)getDigits(); and get the char dec value for 49 50 and 51 and not 150. but even if that worked i still dont know how to put them together into a char array, let alone to then put 1000 of these into another array to then send them away as one packet.

Also i could just use a for loop and send my readings in that way, but that would slow everything down and i would not get a very good audio out of it.

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot just send the raw binary data?  That would be the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Keep in mind that UDP packets can be lost or delivered out of order. You'll need to account for both of these in your protocol. [The most reliable and efficient udp packet size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993000/the-most-reliable-and-efficient-udp-packet-size) and other questions may also be worth searching for and reading.

Comment: Side note: `int digit[length];` isn't 100% kosher. `length needs to be a compile-time constant to get a Standard-compliant array.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes that would work too but then how do i send all 1000 elements in raw binary data at the same time?

Comment: Echoing Jeremy's comment, `Udp.write((char*)digit);` would probably be the simplest and most efficient way to do it. Just make sure the [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and the size of `int` is sorted out at both ends

Comment: Ah. 1000, not 3. 1000 probably will not fit in a single UDP packet. Often they can only hold about 1500 bytes. You may need to develop a small data protocol sequence number (so you can ensure ordering and ask for retransmits of lost data), number of integers in packet and then the `int` in a binary blob. Maybe cap it off with a CRC because UDP doesn't guarantee a any defenses against data corruption.

Comment: *"The thought is that 'return digit[0] + digit[1] + digit[2]' would give me for example 49, 50, 51. and not 150 (the sum)"* -- Well, when you use addition, you do tend to get a sum, with a notable exception for `std::string` (but that is not applicable here).

Comment: You are aware that UDP packets have a very limited size?

Comment: @JonathanBracke You'd want to call the `size_t write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size)` method, with the first argument being the pointer to the start of your array (e.g. `(const uint8 *)digit`, and the second buffer being the number of bytes to send (e.g. `sizeof(digit)`)

Comment: @user4581301  and JeremyFriesner, thank you very much for your help, I got it to work now!